# Разные ip у сайта. ping и 2ip.ru показывают разные ip адреса

Tags: безопасность

Извиняюсь за оффтоп. Посмотрела ролик с канала хауди, где он говорит про то, что если даже на сайте зелёный замок и вы видете что адрес тот же, то это ещё не значит, что вы не взломаны. Если айпи сайта через сервис 2ip.ru , не совпадает с айпи когда мы ping-уем сайт, то нужно бить тревогу. На данный момент, 2ip.ru показывает ip от vk.com 87.240.129.71, а пинг 87.240.182.224.

Айпишники чуточку отличаются. Я так понимаю что пингу отправляется ответ с другого сервера vk, так ?

Comment: `nslookup vk.com` там 4 адреса как минимум. И перестаньте смотреть "псевдо" научные каналы и бить по ним тревогу или быть спокойными. Учите матчасть.

Comment: Поняла.Значит если бы айпишник был из другого диапазона, то значит dns спуфинг.

Comment: Айпишники могут быть вообще какие угодно — какие админы ВК захотят прописать, такие и будут. Это может быть dns спуфинг, а может и не быть

Comment: А как тогда проверить есть dns спуфинг или нет ?

Comment: Если уж доводить данные «ролика» до логического завершения — даже если зелёный замочек и все IP-адреса совпадают, это ещё не значит, что вы не взломаны. Если на вашем компьютере вирус, который хочет подсматривать в ваш ВК — он и ip-адрес подменять вам не будет (ибо зачем), и замочек какой нужно подрисует.

Comment: Проверила через dnsleak.com и dnsleaktest.com. Сайты показывают Бельгию. А свой айпи у меня российский... Мне страшно

Comment: ДНС сервера могут раздавать разные IP в разных регионах, что бы пользователи обращались к ближайшему серверу.

Comment: На Ютюбе в основном сосредоточение школьных нубов с псевдо знаниями, и прочих неадекватов - не обращайте на них внимание :) По вопросу, серверные пулы с распределенной нагрузкой это реалии наших дней, другими словами, это нормально.